# Definition of a field homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Given a field $F$ of characteristic zero, say $F=\mathbb{R}$, what is the minimal requirement for a function $\mu:F\to F$ to be a field homomorphism? (Do we need to require two axioms, one for addition and one for multiplication,  or can you encompass everything in one axiom?)

Comment: as a field is basically a ring (with some additional "nice" features), so any field homomorphism must satisfy the conditions for ring homomorphism.

Comment: Of course, but I am asking if you can require everything in one axiom, like for example, $\mu(xy+z)=x\mu(y)+z$, or something like this...

Comment: in case your field is $\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)=x.f(1)$ and the possibilities for $f(1)$ are either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Are you saying that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a non-zero field homomorphism then $f$ is the identity?...

Comment: Yes, until it is the trivial homomorphism. You need continuity arguments to show this.

Answer (score 3):

One can insist on two conditions:
(i) $\mu(a+b) = \mu(a)+\mu(b)$
(ii) $\mu(ab)=\mu(a)\mu(b)$
or the single condition
(i)$': \mu(ac+b)=\mu(a)\mu(c)+\mu(b)$,
but the difference is cosmetic. The amount of work involved in checking the combined single condition is the same as in checking the two separate conditions. (Aside: the word axiom is not generally used for conditions defining  a homomorphism.)

Comment: Thanks. And they are equivalent, right? I mean, do they give out exactly the same information for $\mu$? Also, $\mu(0)=0$ and $\mu(1)=1$ are trivially satisfied in both cases, right?

Comment: yes, $\mu(a)=\mu(1.a) =\mu(1).\mu(a) \forall a$ and such arguments will force $\mu(1)$ to be 1. But the real things in field theory is in theory of equations, Galois groups etc, not in this minor economy of conditions.

Comment: The zero-map satisfies (i), (ii) and (i)', so you'll need to explicitly require that $\mu(1) = 1$. The condition $\mu(0) = 0$ does follow from (i) and from (i)'.